# Moving or shuffling the vsplit windows left and right

Tags: linux, vim

I am using vim editor and have split windows using `vsplit`. I have 3 vertical split windows in `A` `B` `C` order. Is it possible to shuffle the windows to `B` `A` `C` order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<ctrl-w> + H` to move the currently selected window to the far left (Upper case H)

So if you cursor was in pane B you could do `<c-w>H` to move B left and A will take its place in the middle

Take a look at [`:h window-moving`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window-moving) for other options in moving windows around.

```
5. Moving windows around                                window-moving


CTRL-W x                                        CTRL-W_x CTRL-W_CTRL-X
CTRL-W CTRL-X   Without count: Exchange current window with next one.  If there
                is no next window, exchange with previous window.
                With count: Exchange current window with Nth window (first
                window is 1).  The cursor is put in the other window.
                When vertical and horizontal window splits are mixed, the
                exchange is only done in the row or column of windows that the
                current window is in.

...

                                                CTRL-W_H
CTRL-W H        Move the current window to be at the far left, using the
                full height of the screen.  This works like closing the
                current window and then creating another one with
                ":vert topleft split", except that the current window contents
                is used for the new window.
                {not available when compiled without the +vertsplit feature}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to achieve `ABC->BAC`, cursor in B, do @Fdinoff suggested, if cursor in A, `<c-w> +x` exchange current window with next one.

Personally I used it often when I opened two windows side by side, and want to exchange their positions.

`<c-w> H` is also useful to switch H-split two windows to V-split.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. If I really would like to have vim shuffle the windows, I
would do it like this:

```
au VimEnter * exe (localtime()%winnr('$')+1). "wincmd R|1wincmd w"
```